# Filter objects against multiple values, only returning perfect matches

Tags: javascript, arrays, firebase

I have a set of recipe objects, each including an `ingredients` key with an array of values - like this:

```
'soup': {'ingredients': ['carrot', 'pepper', 'tomato']}, 
'pie': {'ingredients': ['carrot', 'steak', 'potato']}, 
'stew': {'ingredients': ['steak', 'pepper', 'tomato']}
```

For each recipe, I want to take an array of values and query the `ingredients` array - returning only recipes that match **all** values.

For example:

```
var shoppingList = ['carrot', 'steak', 'tomato', 'pepper']

// returns: soup, stew
```

I've tried using `Array.prototype.filter()`, which returns objects that contain **any** of the values queried. But I need to return only objects that contain **all** values.

In other words, if I don't have any potato, don't tell me I can make a pie.

The data is coming from a Firebase query originally, but AFAIK it isn't possible to do this server side using Firebase.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which database product are you using?  Cloud Firestore or Realtime Database?  Please edit the question to show the code and (more detailed) database structure that isn't working the way you expect.

Comment: *"I've tried using `Array.prototype.filter()`, which returns objects that contain **any** of the values queried."* Could you add what you've tried to the question?

Comment: @3limin4t0r I think they want to query in Firebase, not filter in code, although that may be an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Extract the key-value pairs from your object with [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)
2. Filter out any that don't have all of their `ingredients` in the `shoppingList` with [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) and [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes).
3. Use [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to get just the keys.

```js
var recipes = {
  'soup': {'ingredients': ['carrot', 'pepper', 'tomato']}, 
  'pie': {'ingredients': ['carrot', 'steak', 'potato']}, 
  'stew': {'ingredients': ['steak', 'pepper', 'tomato']}
};

var shoppingList = ['carrot', 'steak', 'tomato', 'pepper']

var result = Object.entries(recipes)//1. get the key-value pairs
  .filter(([key, {ingredients}]) => ingredients.every(t => shoppingList.includes(t))) //2. filter them
  .map(([key]) => key) //3. get the keys only

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.every()` with `.includes()` inside the `.filter()` callback.

```
return query.every(q => obj.taggedItems.includes(q))
```