# Query an array of objects in JavaScript, matching against multiple criteria

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, lodash

I'm trying to query an array of objects in JavaScript, and return objects that match a specific filter criteria.

I've managed - [thanks to help from others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58403251/filter-objects-against-multiple-values-only-returning-perfect-matches) - to filter a simple object, but now I need to apply the same thing to a more complex object.

```
  // Simple object query:

  var recipes = {
    'soup': {'ingredients': ['carrot', 'pepper', 'tomato']}, 
    'pie': {'ingredients': ['carrot', 'steak', 'potato']}, 
    'stew': {'ingredients': ['steak', 'pepper', 'tomato']}
  };

  var shoppingList = ['carrot', 'steak', 'tomato', 'pepper']

  var result = Object.entries(recipes)//1. get the key-value pairs
    .filter(([key, {ingredients}]) => ingredients.every(t =>       shoppingList.includes(t))) //2. filter them
    .map(([key]) => key) //3. get the keys only

  console.log(result);

  // More complex object:

  var itemsTest = [
    {
      uid: 1,
      items: [
        { item: { uid: "a" } },
        { item: { uid: "b" } },
        { item: { uid: "g" } }
      ]
    },
    {
      uid: 2,
      items: [
        { item: { uid: "b" } },
        { item: { uid: "q" } },
        { item: { uid: "f" } }
      ]
    },
    }
  ];

  var filter = ["b", "q", "f"]

  // Expect filter to return {uid: 2, items}
  }
```

The recipes filter works great. But now I have a more complex array of objects, it seems the same approach isn't possible.

I want to filter `itemsTest` according to the `uid` of each item in the `items` array. I'd be happy to use lodash, if it makes life easier.

I tried to flatten the array of objects using `Object.entries()`, to no avail.

```
  var flattened = objectMap(itemsList, function(value) {
    return Object.entries(value);
  });

  var result = flattened.filter(([key, { uid }]) =>
      uid.every(t => filter.includes(t))
    )
```

I also tried a simplified approach filtering with one value using `Array.filter.prototype()`, which doesn't work either:

```
var newArray = flattened.filter(function(el) {
  return el.uid <= 2
});
console.log(newArray)
```

Any help understanding how to navigate an object like this would be great.

Comment: great, what have you tried?

Comment: I've added some more context for you to see what I've tried. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Array.find()` (or `Array.filter()` to iterate the array of objects. Now use `Array.every()`, and for each item check if it's `uid` is included in the `filter` array.

```js
const itemsTest = [{"uid":1,"items":[{"item":{"uid":"a"}},{"item":{"uid":"b"}},{"item":{"uid":"g"}}]},{"uid":2,"items":[{"item":{"uid":"b"}},{"item":{"uid":"q"}},{"item":{"uid":"f"}}]}];

const filter = ["b", "q", "f"];

const result = itemsTest.find(({ items }) => // use filter instead of find to get multiple items
  items.every(o => filter.includes(o.item.uid))
);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.js"></script>
```